# How can I develop a select all/deselect all for duallistbox in aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, multi-select, lightning-duallistbox, lightningselect

I'm building an AURA component that has dualListBox that is dependent on on lightning:select (https://prnt.sc/mc05yPEzmBO7), so based on the value selected on the lightning:select I populate the dualListBox with different values.

It there any way I can develop extra two buttons and will serve as Select all (and all available values from dualListBox become selected values, and vice versa all Selected values become available values)?

The code for the dualListBox is below:

```
<b><lightning:dualListbox aura:id="selectOptions" 
                                  name="Select Options" 
                                  label="Choose dimensions" 
                                  sourceLabel="Available dimensions" 
                                  selectedLabel="Selected dimensions" 
                                  options="{! v.childList}"
                                  value="{!v.childValue}"   
                                  requiredOptions="{! v.requiredOptions }"
                                  onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/></b>
```

Handlechange function:

```
handleChange: function (cmp, event) {
        // Get the list of the "value" attribute on all the selected options
        var selectedOptionsList = event.getParam("value");
    },
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

I've tried codding this by adding All value in Available values and then in .js if(Value==='all') => set the Selected values List to contain all but I think that's pretty inefficient.

I would really appreciate any other ideas for codding this any other way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go these two approach:-

- Place two button - (select all & deselect all) in your Aura component which will change the selected values, onclick of the button, change the value attribute passed to dual picklist component

  ```
  addAll: function (cmp) {
       var items = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < cmp.get("v.childList").length; i++) {
           items.push(cmp.get("v.childList")[i].value);
       }
       cmp.set("v.childValue", items);
   },
   removeAll: function (cmp) {
       var items = [];
       cmp.set("v.childValue", items);
   },
  ```
- Or you can build  [your own dualpicklist](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/dueling-picklist/) to have custom buttons at desired place and use the same logic used in first approach